# Hibernate HQL Join with composite Key

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

i'm having some problems trying to write a HQL query to 
join two entities/tables as below defined

CustomersDAO.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customers")
public class CustomerDAO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId 
private CustomerNaming name;

@ManyToOne
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE) 
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn (name="city"), @JoinColumn(name="state"),@JoinColumn(name="via") })
private Address indirizzo;

@Column (name="email")
private String email;

@Column (name="mailinglist")
private boolean mailinglist;

@Column (name="sex")
private String sex;

public CustomerDAO()
{
    indirizzo=new Address();
    name=new CustomerNaming();
}



public CustomerNaming getNome() {
    return name;
}
public void setNome(CustomerNaming nome) {
    this.name = nome;
}

public Address getIndirizzo() {
    return indirizzo;
}
public void setIndirizzo(Address indirizzo) {
    this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public boolean isMailinglist() {
    return mailinglist;
}
public void setMailinglist(boolean mailinglist) {
    this.mailinglist = mailinglist;
}
public String getSex() {
    return sex;
}
public void setSex(String sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customer :  [nome=" + name.getNome()
            + ", cognome=" + name.getCognome() + ", indirizzo=" + indirizzo
            + ", email=" + email + ", mailinglist=" + mailinglist
            + ", sex=" + sex + "]";
}


}
```

CustomerNaming.java

```java
@Embeddable
public class CustomerNaming implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column (name="nome")
private String nome;

@Column (name="cognome")
private String cognome;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getCognome() {
    return cognome;
}
public void setCognome(String cognome) {
    this.cognome = cognome;
}



}
```

Address.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="indirizzi")
public class Address implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private AddressKey key;

@Column (name="cap")
private String cap;
//private ArrayList<State> state=new ArrayList<State>();

public Address(){
    key=new AddressKey();
}

public AddressKey getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(AddressKey key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public String getCap() {
    return cap;
}
public void setCap(String cap) {
    this.cap = cap;
}


}
```

AddressKey.java

```java
@Embeddable
public class AddressKey implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name="via", nullable=false)
private String via;
@Column (name="city", nullable=false)
private String city;
@Column (name="state", nullable=false)
private String state;

public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public String getVia() {
    return via;
}
public void setVia(String via) {
    this.via = via;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

}
```

As you can see i have (to try this...i'm still learning hibernate...)
create a composite PK in address, mapped by AddressKey

so i have to create a composite join to do the search, but without success

this is my last (not best...lol) try...

```
        Query q=s.createQuery("FROM CustomerDAO cust JOIN (cust.indirizzo.key.via   cust.indirizzo.key.city  , cust.indirizzo.key.state) as indirizzo WHERE  cust.name.nome=:nome and cust.name.cognome like :cognome and cust.indirizzo.key.via like :via and cust.indirizzo.key.city like :city and cust.indirizzo.cap like :cap and cust.indirizzo.key.state like :state and cust.sex like :sex and c.email like :mail and cust.mailinglist like :mailinglist")
                .setString("nome","\'%"+c.getNome().getNome()+"%\'")
                .setString("cognome", c.getNome().getCognome())
                .setString("via", c.getIndirizzo().getKey().getVia())
                .setString("city", c.getIndirizzo().getKey().getCity())
                .setString("cap", c.getIndirizzo().getCap())
                .setString("state", c.getIndirizzo().getKey().getState())
                .setString("sex", c.getSex())
                .setString("mail",c.getEmail());
        if(q!=null)
            customers=(List<Object[]>)q.list();
```

In some case i've received a null Query from createQuery...

in this case...it simply can't recognise the query

```
 org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 43 [FROM myapp.customer.CustomerDAO cust JOIN (cust.indirizzo.key.via   cust.indirizzo.key.city  , cust.indirizzo.key.state) as indirizzo WHERE  cust.name.nome=:nome and cust.name.cognome like :cognome and cust.indirizzo.key.via like :via and cust.indirizzo.key.city like :city and cust.indirizzo.cap like :cap and cust.indirizzo.key.state like :state and cust.sex like :sex and c.email like :mail and cust.mailinglist like :mailinglist]
```

note than a simpler search as below written works perfectly...

```
List<CustomerDAO> customers=(List<CustomerDAO>)(s.createQuery("from CustomerDAO where nome=:nome and cognome=:cognome").setString("nome", nome).setString("cognome", cognome)).list();
```

thanks for any help

regards
Umberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok

it was in fact far simplier

the query must be without any "join" addition and worked...

example below

```
Query q=s.createQuery("FROM CustomerDAO cust WHERE  cust.name.nome like :nome ");
```

thanks however for the help!

regards

Umberto